# Incompatible convert types when printing out ArrayList element

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Attempting to print out an element from an arraylist within a method. Keep getting incompatible types error.

Been attempting to debug for 20 minutes. Brand new to Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> p1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    p1.add(0);
    p1.add(1);
    p1.add(2);
    System.out.println(getAverage(p1));
  }

  public static int getAverage (ArrayList arr) {
    return arr.get(1);
  }
}
```

Main.java:19: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int

return arr.get(i);}

Comment: Change `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: THANKS worked. I should have known that!

Answer (score 0):

//Use Instead,

```
public static int getAverage (ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
return arr.get(1);  }
```